# Returning an object from a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, database, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure which reads data from a local db and creates an object and returns it. My problem is i have not worked with stored procedures so i don't have much knowledge about it.

I know how to use stored procedures to store data to a database but i don't know how to return data through stored procedures.

Below is the stored procedure which i have created to return an object.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_Advertisements]
AS
BEGIN
    Select * From  Advertisements;         
END
```

I know the above stored procedure only selects the records but What i want to do is :

1. Select one record at a time from the advertisement table
2. Create an object of advertisement class and pass the values read from the advertisement table
3. Return the object
4. Continue the above procedure until the full table is read.

Advertisement object has the following properties : 
- topic
- content

How do i achieve this? Please help , i tried to do it myself but i am confused with the returning part.

Thank you for your time

Comment: why do you want to `Create an object of advertisement`(i think like LINQ to SQL)? Without Creating that object you can read all records form that table

Comment: could you tell me how to do that? It will be really useful.

Comment: i posted answer try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

this is for SQL server and ASP.NET

```
string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection sqlCnn ;
            SqlCommand sqlCmd ;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            int i = 0;
            string sql = null;

            connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
// this should be always in web.config file
            sql = "Select * from Advertisements";

            sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                sqlCnn.Open();
                sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn);
                adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
                adapter.Fill(ds);


                adapter.Dispose();
                sqlCmd.Dispose();
                sqlCnn.Close();


//in ds You will get a Table 
    foreach(DataRow row in thisTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach(DataColumn column in thisTable.Columns)
            {
               Response.write((row[column]+"</br>");
// read all values of table
            }
    }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```